Mail sending error with SimpleJavaMailer library
I am trying to send mail with SimpleJavaMailer library. But it is failing. The mail server is hosted by me. If I use NodeJs NodeMailer module their working. I have sent mail from mail box also it is working fine but when I am trying to send mail java spring boot it is failed.
The is here:
org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerException: Failed to send email [Subject: 'check mail'], reason: Third party error
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.handleException(SendMailClosure.java:85)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.executeClosure(SendMailClosure.java:72)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.AbstractProxyServerSyncingClosure.run(AbstractProxyServerSyncingClosure.java:59)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerImpl.sendMail(MailerImpl.java:364)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerImpl.sendMail(MailerImpl.java:349)
    at link.team71.emailserver.services.MailService.sendMail(MailService.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$toSupplier$0(FutureUtils.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.team71.link, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching mail.team71.link found.
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2245)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:729)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:225)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:174)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportConnectionHelper.connectTransport(TransportConnectionHelper.java:42)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.runOnSessionTransport(TransportRunner.java:80)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.sendMessage(TransportRunner.java:56)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.executeClosure(SendMailClosure.java:69)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching mail.team71.link found.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:647)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:467)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:363)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2193)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching mail.team71.link found.
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:207)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:417)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1463)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1431)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:631)
    ... 40 more

I have setup up the ssl on the mail server also.
My code is:
 public CompletableFuture<Object> sendMail(String usermail, String subject, String content) {

        Email email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
                .from("Team 71", dotenv.get("EMAIL"))
                .to(usermail)
                .withSubject(subject)
                .withHTMLText(content)
                .buildEmail();

        Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder
                .withSMTPServer( dotenv.get("EMAIL_HOST"), 465, dotenv.get("EMAIL"), dotenv.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD"))
                .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTPS)
                .trustingAllHosts(true)// Use SMTPS for port 465
                .buildMailer();

        try {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mailer.sendMail(email));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mailer.sendMail(email));
        }
    }

I have tried the spring mail library first but that also show the same problem

If you are hosting your own email server and trying to send email through it, it needs to have a valid certificate. To resolve this, you need to ensure that the SSL/TLS certificate on your email server is configured correctly and includes mail.team71.link

I have already setup the ssl for the mail. openssl s_client -connect mail.team71.link:465 -showcerts this showing that the cert.

Does it show this endpoint on the SAN section? Certificate chain > X509v3 Subject Alternative Name

Your config file application.properties ,
add spring.mail.properties.mail.stmp.ssl.trust=mail.team71.link

Not solve the problem. @life888888

No, that end point nothing shows anything. But it gives a log
@JorgeCampos

Then your configuration is wrong. You need to research how to set it up correctly (sorry, my knowledge is limited to what is needed).
